# Media query not working on mobile portrait mode

Tags: html, css

When applying the following for media query, it is not working on mobile portrait mode. It works fine on mobile landscape mode and desktop. 
Here is my code

```css
.post-table-new {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  color: #000
}

.post-table-new tr,
.post-table-new th,
.post-table-new td {
  border: 1.5px solid #000
}

.post-table-new {
  background-color: #fff
}

.post-table-new td,
.post-table-new th {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}

.post-table-new th {
  background-color: #fe074e;
  color: #fff
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  td.hide-col {
    display: none;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: collapse;
  }
  th.hide-col {
    display: none;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: collapse;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta charset=UTF-8>
<meta name=viewport id=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<table class="post-table-new">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading</th>
      <th>Heding 2</th>
      <th class="hide-col">Heding 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="hide-col">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td class="hide-col">6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here i want to hide one column of the table. It is working fine in Desktop when reducing size of the browser.It is also working fine in mobile landscape mode but it is not working in mobile portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

```css
// add orientation media query, landscape or portrait

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) , screen and (orientation:landscape)
```